# Openshift v3.10 jenkins pipeline tutorial won't build

Tags: jenkins

I have an Openshift v3.10 5 node cluster up and running.  I'm starting to look at configuring a Jenkins pipeline build configuration, so I started following the tutorial here: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/dev_guide/dev_tutorials/openshift_pipeline.html

I created new project: oc create infrastructure
Created ephemeral app (Just testing this all out for now):

```
oc new-app jenkins-ephemeral
```

This created successfully, i.e. created jenkins route, deploymentconfig, serviceaccount, etc... and reported success

I then created the file and build config (nodejs-sample-pipeline.yaml)

```
oc create -f nodejs-sample-pipeline.yaml
```

Started the build config:

```
oc start-build nodejs-sample-pipeline
build "nodejs-sample-pipeline-1" started
```

If I look at the build in the console it shows Build #1 No stages have started with a status of New and Duration says waiting for 21 minutes, 48 seconds (and counting)

If I do: `oc get pods`   I don't see a jenkins pod running which is what I would expect.

I pulled the registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/jenkins-2-rhel7 as stated here: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/using_images/other_images/jenkins.html, but I pulled it from my Nexus proxy repo, so it has the following tag: blah.blah.com:8084/openshift3/jenkins-2-rhel7

I would expect this image to be running, but for some reason it is not.  Any idea what I am missing or how to troubleshoot?  Not having a running image, I'm not sure where/how to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Jenkins-rhel7 image just needed to be tagged openshift/jenkins:2